# Calling a function with [0] Codeigniter Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was working on a project in a development server (uses PHP 5.5.0)

When I transferred the project to the live server (uses PHP 5.3.27)

I found out that using this syntax causes the error:

```
$param['info']  = $this->model_users->get_logged()[0]
```

So, is there a way to fix this? I mean instead of rewriting it without the pointer [0].

Comment: Use this type $param['info']  = ($this->model_users->get_logged())[0]

Comment: @MikeB Yes it is unfortunately. I've searched for multiple of times but didn't get that question. Shall I vote to close?

Comment: @iMohammad No worries, it's one of those things that's difficult to search for unless you know the term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature of array derefernce was introduced in PHP 5.4. Therefor you cannot use it on a PHP 5.3 Production server.

There are at least two solutions. One is the idea of upgrading your PHP version on the server (good idea).

The other one is just a change in the code base:

```
$tmp_logged = $this->users_model->get_logged();
$param['info'] = $tmp_logged[0];
```